# Build from docker clang fail v1.7.0

Tags: nodeos, docker, error, build

I have been build nodeos v1.7.0 on docker. but failed.

build logs:

```
[447/596] Building CXX object libraries/chain/CMakeFiles/eosio_chain.dir/controller.cpp.o
FAILED: libraries/chain/CMakeFiles/eosio_chain.dir/controller.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/clang++-4.0   -I/eos/libraries/chain/include -Ilibraries/chain/include -I/eos/libraries/chain/../wasm-jit/Include -I/eos/libraries/wabt -Ilibraries/wabt -I/eos/libraries/fc/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/openssl/include -I/eos/libraries/fc/vendor/websocketpp -I/eos/libraries/fc/secp256k1/upstream -I/eos/libraries/fc/secp256k1/upstream/include -I/eos/libraries/chainbase/include -I/eos/libraries/wasm-jit/Source/Runtime/../../../chain/include -I/eos/libraries/softfloat/source/include -I/eos/libraries/softfloat/source/8086-SSE -I/eos/libraries/softfloat/build/Linux-x86_64-GCC -I/eos/libraries/builtins -I/eos/libraries/builtins../softfloat/source/include -Wall -Wno-invalid-partial-specialization -fcolor-diagnostics -O3 -DNDEBUG   -fcolor-diagnostics -std=gnu++14 -MD -MT libraries/chain/CMakeFiles/eosio_chain.dir/controller.cpp.o -MF libraries/chain/CMakeFiles/eosio_chain.dir/controller.cpp.o.d -o libraries/chain/CMakeFiles/eosio_chain.dir/controller.cpp.o -c /eos/libraries/chain/controller.cpp
clang: error: unable to execute command: Killed
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
clang version 4.0.1-10 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://llvm.org/bugs/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/controller-05c185.cpp
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/controller-05c185.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 

********************
[448/596] Building CXX object libraries/chain/CMakeFiles/eosio_chain.dir/wasm_eosio_validation.cpp.o
[449/596] Building CXX object libraries/chain/CMakeFiles/eosio_chain.dir/apply_context.cpp.o
[450/596] Building CXX object libraries/chain/CMakeFiles/eosio_chain.dir/wasm_eosio_injection.cpp.o
[451/596] Building CXX object libraries/chain/CMakeFiles/eosio_chain.dir/abi_serializer.cpp.o
[452/596] Building CXX object libraries/chain/CMakeFiles/eosio_chain.dir/wasm_interface.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ERROR: Service 'gateway' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev  libusb-1.0-0-dev      && git clone -b $branch https://github.com/EOSIO/eos.git --recursive     && cd eos && echo "$branch:$(git rev-parse HEAD)" > /etc/eosio-version     && cmake -H. -B"/tmp/build" -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWASM_ROOT=/opt/wasm -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++-4.0        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-4.0 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/build -DBUILD_MONGO_DB_PLUGIN=true -DCORE_SYMBOL_NAME=$symbol     && cmake --build /tmp/build --target install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My eos Dockerfile:

```
FROM eosio/builder:v1.7.0 as builder

ARG branch=master
ARG symbol=EOS
ARG phase=beta2

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev  libusb-1.0-0-dev  \
    && git clone -b $branch https://github.com/EOSIO/eos.git --recursive \
    && cd eos && echo "$branch:$(git rev-parse HEAD)" > /etc/eosio-version \
    && cmake -H. -B"/tmp/build" -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWASM_ROOT=/opt/wasm -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++-4.0 \
       -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-4.0 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/build -DBUILD_MONGO_DB_PLUGIN=true -DCORE_SYMBOL_NAME=$symbol \
    && cmake --build /tmp/build --target install

FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG phase=beta2
ARG network=mainnet

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install openssl ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/* /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder /tmp/build/bin /opt/eosio/bin
COPY --from=builder /tmp/build/contracts /contracts
COPY --from=builder /etc/eosio-version /etc
COPY config-${phase}.ini /config.ini
COPY genesis-${network}.json /genesis.json
COPY nodeosd.sh /opt/eosio/bin/nodeosd.sh
COPY nodeosd-recover.sh /opt/eosio/bin/nodeosd-recover.sh
ENV EOSIO_ROOT=/opt/eosio
RUN chmod +x /opt/eosio/bin/nodeosd.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/eosio/bin/nodeosd-recover.sh
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib
ENV PATH /opt/eosio/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

EXPOSE 8888 9876
```

My builder/Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

LABEL author="xiaobo <peterwillcn@gmail.com>" maintainer="Xiaobo <peterwillcn@gmail.com> Huang-Ming Huang <huangh@objectcomputing.com>" version="0.1.1" \
  description="This is a base image for building eosio/eos"

RUN echo 'APT::Install-Recommends 0;' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01norecommends \
  && echo 'APT::Install-Suggests 0;' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01norecommends \
  && apt-get update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y sudo wget curl net-tools ca-certificates unzip gnupg

RUN echo "deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/llvm.list \
  && wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add - \
  && apt-get update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git-core automake autoconf libtool build-essential pkg-config libtool \
     mpi-default-dev libicu-dev python-dev python3-dev libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libgmp-dev \
     clang-4.0 lldb-4.0 lld-4.0 llvm-4.0-dev libclang-4.0-dev ninja-build \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/lib/llvm-4.0/bin/clang 400 \
  && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/lib/llvm-4.0/bin/clang++ 400

RUN wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.9/cmake-3.9.6-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && bash cmake-3.9.6-Linux-x86_64.sh --prefix=/usr/local --exclude-subdir --skip-license \
    && rm cmake-3.9.6-Linux-x86_64.sh

ENV CC clang
ENV CXX clang++

RUN wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.67.0/source/boost_1_67_0.tar.bz2 -O - | tar -xj \
    && cd boost_1_67_0 \
    && ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local \
    && echo 'using clang : 4.0 : clang++-4.0 ;' >> project-config.jam \
    && ./b2 -d0 -j$(nproc) --with-thread --with-date_time --with-system --with-filesystem --with-program_options \
       --with-signals --with-serialization --with-chrono --with-test --with-context --with-locale --with-coroutine --with-iostreams toolset=clang link=static install \
    && cd .. && rm -rf boost_1_67_0

RUN wget https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases/download/1.10.2/mongo-c-driver-1.10.2.tar.gz -O - | tar -xz \
    && cd mongo-c-driver-1.10.2 \
    && mkdir cmake-build && cd cmake-build \
    && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DENABLE_BSON=ON \
        -DENABLE_SSL=OPENSSL -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP=OFF -DENABLE_STATIC=ON .. \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install \
    && cd ../../ && rm -rf mongo-c-driver-1.10.2

RUN git clone --depth 1 --single-branch --branch release_40 https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm.git \
    && git clone --depth 1 --single-branch --branch release_40 https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang.git llvm/tools/clang \
    && cd llvm \
    && cmake -H. -Bbuild -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/wasm -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD= -DLLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=WebAssembly -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  \
    && cmake --build build --target install \
    && cd .. && rm -rf llvm

RUN git clone --depth 1 -b releases/v3.3 https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver \
    && cd mongo-cxx-driver/build \
    && cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .. \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install \
    && cd ../../ && rm -rf mongo-cxx-driver

RUN git clone https://github.com/cryptonomex/secp256k1-zkp.git \
    && cd secp256k1-zkp \
    && ./autogen.sh \
    && ./configure \
    && make -j$( nproc ) \
    && sudo make install \
    && cd .. && rm -rf secp256k1-zkp

RUN mkdir  ~/wasm-compiler \
    && cd ~/wasm-compiler \
    && git clone --depth 1 --single-branch --branch release_40 https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm.git \
    && cd llvm/tools \
    && git clone --depth 1 --single-branch --branch release_40 https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang.git \
    && cd .. \
    && mkdir build \
    && cd build \
    && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=.. -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD= -DLLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=WebAssembly -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../ \
    && make -j$( nproc ) install \

``
```

Comment: I'd recommend posting an issue on the related repo: https://github.com/eosio/

Comment: @Nat Thank you. I some retried before posting an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh.. I'm so idiot.

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker

should be enough 7 GB memory.